# How to query documents using document IDs in AngularFire?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to query documents based on document IDs but I am unable to get the data using

```
this.afs.collection<books>('books' , ref => ref.where( ref.id , 'in' , ['4L9uf4w5fqFXlU0uLbEM','bpXgEOmYqGor8uhUz2uq','tJFYPJcLMYNS8qnaUtMv'])).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => {
            return actions.map( a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                return {...data};
            });
        })
     );
```

afs is of type AngularFirestore

I don't know if above code is correct.

I tried the solution mentioned at : 
[Query firestore database for document id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876754/query-firestore-database-for-document-id/52252264#52252264) by replacing ref.id with firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() but I get an error :

> 'firebase' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module.

Help me in retrieving the data.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text on Stack Overflow.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: From searching for this error message, it seems like you may be missing an import. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46092807, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46276558, and more

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can't find any imports for the same in the package '@angular/fire/firestore'

Comment: @sachinrathod I found this in one of my projects, give it a try: `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

Comment: @Stratubas I referred this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-firebase and imported  ```import * as firebase from 'firebase';``` and it worked and yes I tried import suggested by you it is also working. Thank You. I will write answer.

Comment: @sachinrathod If I remember correctly, importing from `'firebase'` gives a warning in the console. Check it before answering.

Comment: @Stratubas yes you are right ```import * as firebase from 'firebase';``` gives warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could solve it by replacing `ref.id` with `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` and importing 
`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

The issue can also be solved by importing `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` but as mentioned by @Stratubas in the comments section above import gives

> warning in the console

So, it is advised to use `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

And finally my code looks:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

this.afs.collection<books>('books' , ref => ref.where( firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() , 'in' , ['4L9uf4w5fqFXlU0uLbEM','bpXgEOmYqGor8uhUz2uq','tJFYPJcLMYNS8qnaUtMv'])).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => {
            return actions.map( a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                return {...data};
            });
        })
     );
```

Comment: This code helps solve queries that have security rules, +1 mate!

Comment: @KingDarBoja only when you know document ID ;)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to add an `id` string property in your documents when creating them (make it equal to the actual id of the documents) and use that for querying.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve data without adding id string property to document?